# groovy script + run CLI command + WIN XP

Tags: windows, command-line, groovy

I have the following command in my groovy script

```
   println "cmd /c remove_files.bat".execute().text
```

Groovy runs the BAT file - **remove_files.bat** ,  but the BAT file stop on the question:

```
  do you really want to remove them [y/n]?
```

this question is the single question that I need to answer in order to continue

so

Anyone have a smart idea what need to **add/change** in the execute groovy command in order to answer this question automatically ?

**remove_files.bat** file

```
  @echo off


  ECHO all files will remove from C:\backup directory.

  set /p delBuild=Delete do you really want to remove them [y/n]?

   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
def proc = [ 'cmd', '/c', 'remove_files.bat' ].execute()
proc << 'y'

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(output, output)
println output.toString()
```

Not sure if it will work, I don't have a Windows machine to test it on :-(

Comment: hi I guess the option of expect is little complicated?